# Unexpected Match behavior in sshd_config

Tags: configuration, sshd, openssh

I'm trying to configure the following restrictions in my `sshd_config`:

1. Users with local IP addresses face no restrictions
2. Users with non-local IP addresses, who are in the `sftp` group, are allowed to use sftp in a chroot jail
3. Users with non-local IP addresses, who are not in the `sftp` group, are not allowed to do anything.

Here's what I came up with:

```
Match Address 10.0.0.0/24,172.16.0.0/20,192.168.0.0/16
        X11Forwarding yes

Match Address *,!10.0.0.0/24,!172.16.0.0/20,!192.168.0.0/16 Group sftp
        X11Forwarding no
        AllowTcpForwarding no
        ChrootDirectory %h
        ForceCommand internal-sftp

Match Address *,!10.0.0.0/24,!172.16.0.0/20,!192.168.0.0/16 Group *,!sftp
        X11Forwarding no
        AllowTcpForwarding no
        ForceCommand /sbin/nologin
```

The problem: when I try to login from an internal address, as a non-sftp user, I get rejected; the third Match triggered.

According to the `sshd_config` manpage, a Match is only satisfied if all of its clauses are satisfied, but in my case, the first clause is not satisfied (I am coming in from a machine with a 172.16.0.0/20 IP address), only the second one is (I am not in the sftp group).

Is the `sshd_config` manpage wrong? Is it possible to do what I am trying to do?

UPDATE: at @steve's suggestion, I ran sshd in debug mode, and got this:

```
debug1: userauth-request for user root service ssh-connection method none
debug1: attempt 0 failures 0
debug1: connection from 172.19.187.49 matched 'Address *,!10.0.0.0/24,!172.16.0.0/20,!192.168.0.0/16' at line 144
debug1: user root does not match group list sftp at line 144
debug1: connection from 172.19.187.49 matched 'Address *,!10.0.0.0/24,!172.16.0.0/20,!192.168.0.0/16' at line 150
debug1: user root matched group list *,!sftp at line 150
debug1: PAM: initializing for "root"
```

The no-internal-adress clauses are matching; also, the first Match is not mentioned in the debug log, which seems odd.

UPDATE:

As @Gilles pointed out, my address specifications as shown above are incorrect. What I should have used was 10.0.0.0/8, not 10.0.0.0/24, and 172.16.0.0/12, not 172.16.0.0/20. I was counting the mask bits down from 32 instead of up from 0. Yikes.

With the corrected addresses, the configuration works. Thanks Gilles and Uriel!

(I also changed the /sbin/nologin in the last line to /bin/false; the former leads to a strange error message from sftp: `Received message too long 1416128883`.)

Comment: worth using `sshd -d` to get some debug output, see what's happening ?

Comment: @ThomasOkken Please edit your question to add information. The first directive does not match 172.19.187.49. You say you're coming from an IP address in the 172.16.0.0/20 block, but 172.19.187.49 isn't. Did you mean to write 172.16.0.0/12?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your netmaks are incorrect. If you want to include private networks, you should use :

```
10.0.0.0/8,172.16.0.0/12,192.168.0.0/16
```

This is probably why you do not match, rather than a `ssh` bug.

Answer (score 1):

I was answering similar question on [Superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/952235/why-arent-my-negative-matches-working/952261#952261), but after the responses I am not longer sure if it is right.

In short, I believe that it is currently not possible and even `openssh-7.0` is out, but these bugs were not fixed so we will have to urge upstream.

Also there is alternative answer with positive feedback, but I guess this is the way how you are trying to achieve your results. I didn't try it, but this looks like it is related only for groups. Otherwise match `*,!something` doesn't make much sense.

Not to blame upstream all the way here and not bringing any constructive feedback, I can recommend you to run two separate `sshd` services on different ports. One would user `AllowGroup sftp` and force `sftp` server. The other would answer only to requests from you internal network.